# Perform Left Search function using Pandas

Tags: excel, regex, pandas

This is my very first question linking to my first Python project.
To put it simple, I have 2 columns of data in Excel like this (first 6 rows):

```
destination_area   |   destination_code
SG37.D0            |   SG37.D
SG30.C0            |   SG30.C
SG4.A3.P           |   SG4.A
SG15.C16           |   SG15.C
SG35.D02           |   SG35.D
SG8.A5.BC          |   SG8.A
```

So in Excel, I'm using a function to get destination code by finding first "." in the cell & return all characters from the left of it, plus 1 character:

```
=IfError(left(E2,search(".",E2)+1),"")
```

Now I want to execute it using str.extract

```
df1['destination_code'] = df1['destination_area'].str.extract(r"(?=(.*[0-9][.][A-Z]))", expand = False)  

print(df1['destination_area'].head(6),df1['destination_code'].head(6))
```

I almost got what I need but the code still recognize those that have more than 1 "."

```
destination_area   |   destination_code
SG37.D0            |   SG37.D
SG30.C0            |   SG30.C
SG4.A3.P           |   SG4.A3.P
SG15.C16           |   SG15.C
SG35.D02           |   SG35.D
SG8.A5.BC          |   SG8.A5.BC
```

I recognize that my regex is understanding the pattern of {a number + "." + a letter}, which returns all characters for the cases of "SG4.A3.P" and "SG8.A5.BC".
So how to modify my code? Or any better way to perform the code like how Excel does? Thanks in advance

Comment: Use `r"(?=(\w+[.][A-Z]))"` instead?

Comment: flawless modification. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

No need in lookahead. Use

```py
df1['destination_code'] = df1['destination_area'].str.extract(r"^([^.]+\..)", expand=False)
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/o234E3/1). Mind the capturing group, it is enough here to return the value you need.

**Explanation**:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^.]+                    any character except: '.' (1 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .                        any character except \n
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
```

Comment: I see. Just wondering what's the difference between yours and Henry's? And any example shows that the outcome of 2 methods can yield different result?

Comment: @CharlieNguyen Henry's `(?=(\w+[.][A-Z]))` is a zero-width matching assertion that finds a place in string that is followed with one or more letters, digits or underscores, `.` and an uppercase letter, capturing these three and outputting them with `str.extract`. I suggest matching any characters other than a dot followed by the dot and then any character, and returning this value. My solution is mimicking your formula code. You can enhance the expression to your liking and further requirements.